# Using brotli with AWS Cloudfront + S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront, brotli

I'm deploying a React App using Cloudfront and S3 and I would like to enable brotli for compression. I've seen some tutorials that address this problem using lambda@edge. The behavior configuration for my Cloudfront distribution is the following

[image]

I also have the 'Compress Objects Automatically' option set to 'No'. I have associated the two following lambda functions for origin requests and viewer requests, respectively:

- origin request:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Funciton registered on 'Origin Request' CloudFront Event
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  const headers = request.headers;
  const isBr = headers['x-compression'] && headers['x-compression'][0].value === "br";
  const isGzip =  headers['x-compression'] && headers['x-compression'][0].value === "gzip";

  /**
  * Update request path based on custom header
  */  
  let extension = "";
  if(isBr)
    extension = ".br";
  else if(isGzip)
    extension = ".gzip";
  request.uri =  request.uri + extension;
  callback(null, request);
};
```

- viewer request:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Funciton registered on 'Viewer Request' CloudFront Event
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const headers = request.headers;
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));

  /**
   * Detect if brotli is supported by the browser.
   * Pass a custom header x-compression to be captured by the lambda in the origin-request phase.
   */
  if(headers['accept-encoding'] && headers['accept-encoding'][0].value.indexOf('br') > -1) {
    headers['x-compression'] = [{
      key: 'X-Compression',
      value: 'br'
    }];
  }
  else if(headers['accept-encoding'] && headers['accept-encoding'][0].value.indexOf('gzip') > -1){
    headers['x-compression'] = [{
      key: 'X-Compression',
      value: 'gzip'
    }];
  }
  callback(null, request);
};
```

When I tried to open the app using Cloudfront's domain name in the browser in throws an Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character in bundle.js:1. However, when I use S3's endpoint for opening the app it works perfectly. The following is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { 
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                            },                                                      
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                     },
                     { 
                         loader: 'postcss-loader',
                         options: {
                             ident: 'postcss',
                             plugins: () => [
                                 autoprefixer({})
                             ]
                         }
                      }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz',
            threshold: 0,
            minRatio: 2,
            test: /\.(js|css)$/i
          }),
          new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].br',
            algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
            threshold: 0,
            minRatio: 2,
            test: /\.(js|css)$/i,
            compressionOptions: {level: 11}
          })
    ]
};
```

I've placed my code in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/jd-chaves/react-webpack-tutorial) (I've also uploaded the dist/ directory which is the one I upload to S3 for the deployment). I'm new to this technologies so I ran out of ideas. I also tried adding .html and .png extensions to the plugins constructors in the Webpack configuration file but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

CloudFront now supports Brotli edge compression. You can set Compress Objects Automatically to 'Yes' and eliminate the Lambda@Edge function. CloudFront will take your uncompressed files from S3 and can compress cacheable requests to Brotli or Gzip at the edge for you.

See here for specific configuration docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html